# Rails Active Record query including delegated attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

Is it possible to make a query like this? (Pseudo-code)

```
u=User.includes(all_delegated_attributes_from_relationships).all
```

How?

Further explanation:

```
class User<ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :car
  delegate :wheel, :brake, :motor, to: :car, prefix: true
end
```

and then:

```
u=User.includes(delegated_car_parts).all
#<user id: 1, car_id: 1, name: "John", car_wheel: "foo", car_motor: "bar", car_brake: false>
```

I know that this can sound a little odd but I have to add a feature to an old app to export all delegated attributes from a model to CSV and this model has 14 relationships and 300 delegations... I just learnt Demeter's law when I made this app...

Comment: What do you mean by delegated attributes?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming wheel, break and motor are relationships on car, you can do this:

```
User.includes(:car => [:wheel, :brake, :motor]).all
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that's what I need to get but I have a model with many relationships and delegations, and I would like to do it in a more handy way.

Comment: Seems like an odd thing to do.  If you look at the source for delegate (http://apidock.com/rails/Module/delegate) it generates methods, there isn't a list of methods that have been delegated.  So pretty much the best you can do is something like @BroiSatse answer.

Answer (score 2):

There is no build-in method to do this. You could try sth like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :car

  DelegatedCarMethods  = [:wheel, :brake, :motor]
  delegate *DelegatedCarMethods, to: :car, prefix: true

  scope :with_car_delagations, lambda do
    select_array = ["#{table_name}.*"]
    select_array += DelegateCarMethods.map {|method| "#{Car.table_name}.#{method} AS car_#{method}"}
    select(select_array.join(', ')).joins(:car)        
  end
end
```

But it isn't extremely pretty. Why do you need this? Calling `user.wheel` or `user.motor` doesn't feel right.

Comment: Thanks, it can point me in the right direction. I need to do it because I have an old application with many relationships and delegations and the customer asked me for the possibility of exporting all that model to CSV, and that can be very tedious selecting each attribute.